# Integrate Javascript to my Rhodes App

Tags: ruby, rhomobile

in my application. js is a function named 
function helloWorld() {}
what should I do to call this function on an index.erb of a model?

I try to write the function in the application.js

```
$("#changePanel").click(function() {
    var data = "foobar";
    $("#panel").hide().html(data).fadeIn('fast');
});

then I change my layout erb. at the following content
<% if System::get_property('platform') == 'APPLE' || System::get_property('platform') == 'ANDROID' || System::get_property('platform') == 'WP7' || is_bb6 || System::get_property('webview_framework') =~ /^WEBKIT/ %>
      <script src="/public/js/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/public/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/public/jquery/jquery.json-2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

and in my view i added
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <h1>Model001s</h1>
    <a href="<%= Rho::RhoConfig.start_path %>" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse" <%= "data-ajax='false'" if is_bb6 %>>
      Home
    </a>
    <a href="<%= url_for :action => :new %>" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="plus">
      New
    </a>
    </div>

      <div id="panel">test data</div>
      <input id="incre" value="Change Panel" type="button">  </div>
</div>
```

I don´t know whats wrong. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `#changePanel` for your click event to trigger.
I think maybe you should change:

`<input id="incre" value="Change Panel" type="button">  </div>`

to

`<input id="changePanel" value="Change Panel" type="button">  </div>`